# react-select don't focus input when opening options list

Tags: reactjs, react-select

The Select component (https://react-select.com) always focuses the input when opening the dropdown. This is not wanted when on mobile because it causes the virtual keyboard to always open. 
We want the user to be able to tap the dropdown indicator icon on the right on the Select component and see the options without focusing the input, but, if the user taps the area over the input then the focus is given to the input field.

*edit: github.com issue related - https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3526

Comment: try this link, https://github.com/jedwatson/react-select/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mobile

Comment: Thx @windmaomao - I found this issue https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3526 but it doesn't solve the problem, yet :=)

Comment: haven't you solved the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `isSearchable` prop and setting it to false?

You can test this functionality on the first example of [www.react-select.com](http://www.react-select.com)

Click on Select, see keyboard
Now uncheck "Searchable", click select, and you should be focused without a keyboard.

I included images in the referenced react-select issue.

Comment: we want to be able to search items but not immediately